# Canvas line chart AsyncTask in RecyclerView android

Tags: android, canvas, android-asynctask, android-bitmap, listadapter

I put a bitmap at one position of an `ArrayList`  in `AsyncTask`, and then I show it on `ImageView` in `onViewHolderBind()`. But some elements of the list do not display properly

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

```
  @Override
protected void onViewHolderBind(List<SampleBean> list, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ItemVH itemVH = (ItemVH) holder;
    itemholder= itemVH;
    itemVH.tvTitle.setText(list.get(position).title);


     Thread t= new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            imgwidth= itemVH.ımageView.getWidth();
            imgheight= itemVH.ımageView.getHeight();

            globalImg= itemVH.ımageView;
            itemVH.ımageView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

        }
    };
    t.start();

    if(listwithBitmap.get(position).getCanvasBitmap() == null )
     new BackgroundTask().execute(position);

     else
     {
        itemholder.ımageView.setImageBitmap(listwithBitmap.get(position).getCanvasBitmap());
     }

}
```

If you help me, I will really be appreciative. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to draw a line chart for each row in the Sticky header recycler view. I want to do the heavy mathematical operations required for the line chart in the thread to be fast. But some graphics have not been drawn properly and I do not understand why.